# How do I detect a case-insensitive file system in Perl?

Tags: perl, filesystems, case-sensitive

I tried using [`File::Spec->case_tolerant`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec#case_tolerant), but it returns false on HFS+, which is wrong. I suspect it's because [File::Spec::Unix](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec::Unix) always returns false. My current workaround is this function:

```
my $IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE;
sub _is_case_insensitive {
    unless (defined $IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE) {
        $IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE = 0;
        my ($uc) = glob uc __FILE__;
        if ($uc) {
            my ($lc) = glob lc __FILE__;
            $IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE = 1 if $lc;
        }
    }
    return $IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE;
}
```

But that's a hack since: 1) on a case-sensitive file system both of those files might exists; and 2) different volumes can have different file systems.

Comment: What change of behaviour do you intend to make depending on the results of this test? Why can't you just treat every file system as being case-sensitive?

Comment: (*NB:* there must be a CPAN package that does this). This may be too simple - or for that matter too complicated - but would reading a directory of files into an array then running something like:  `say "insensitive" if map { -f && (stat $_)[1] == (stat uc($_))[1]   } @filenames` work?  I can imagine false positives where the inode is the same and there's a hard link to a file with an uppercase version of the original file name ... but then errm what @Borodin said ;-)

Comment: @Borodin I'm [updating the `survey()`  method of Pod::Simple](https://github.com/theory/pod-simple/commit/c169da76d5a5459028848b7753452991ad9f096b) to map module names to files case-insensitively on case-insensitive file systems, so that the the results match what `perldoc` and the `find()` method will find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In truth, every directory considered must be checked on its own. This is because, on Unix-like systems, *any* directory can be a different file system than some other directory. Furthermore, use of `glob` is not very reliable; from [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#System-Interaction):

> Don't count on filename globbing. Use `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir` instead.

But I think that [@borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) is onto something with the use of `-e`. So here's a function that uses `-e` to determine whether the specified directory is on a case-insensitive file system:

```
my %IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE;
sub is_case_insensitive {
    my $dir = shift;
    unless (defined $IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE{$dir}) {
        $IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE{$dir} = -e uc $dir && -e lc $dir;
    }
    return $IS_CASE_INSENSITIVE{$dir};
}
```

You could probably add some heuristics for Windows to just cache the value for the drive letter, since that defines a mount point. And of course, it will fail on case-sensisitve file systems if both uppercase and lowercase variations of the directory exist. But otherwise, unless there is some other way to tell more globally which directories match to which mount points, you have to check for any directory.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make use of the core [`File::Temp`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Temp) module to create a new unique file that has lower-case characters in its name. The file is set to be deleted when the object is destroyed, which is when the subroutine exits if not before.

If the file doesn't exist when access by the upper-cased file name then the filing system is *case-sensitive*.

If the upper-cased name *does exist* then we have to check that we haven't happened upon a file whose upper-case version was already there, so we delete the file. If the upper-case entry has now gone then the filing system is *case-insensitive*.

If the upper-cased name is still there then it is a file that existed before we created the temporary file. We just loop around and create a new temporary file with a different name, although the chances of this happening are absolutely tiny. If you prefer you can minimize this possibility even further by using an outlandish value for `SUFFIX`. Just be careful that the characters you use are valid on any fileing system that you wish to test.

I've tested this on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use File::Temp ();

printf "File system %s case_insensitive\n", case_insensitive() ? "is" : "isn't";


sub case_insensitive {

  while () {

    my $tmp = File::Temp->new(
      TEMPLATE => 'tempXXXXXX',
      SUFFIX   => '.tmp',
      UNLINK   => 1,
    );

    my $uc_filename = uc $tmp->filename;

    return 0 if not -e $uc_filename;
    $tmp = undef;
    return 1 if not -e $uc_filename;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really all that different from mine; you avoid the issue of both files existing, but there’s still the issue of different file systems. This only tells you the case-sensitivity of the file system to which File::Temp writes. I'm probably over-thinking it, though; I suspect it's quite rare to have file systems with different case sensitivities mounted on a single machine.